# AlloyUI (diagram-builder) extends

Tags: javascript, alloy-ui

I'm trying to customise diagram builder, I created new type of node and trying to add custom attributes with custom editor.

I just extend from dropdownCellEditor and it already doesn't work (editor appears, but can not save value, seems save and cancel buttons do not work) :(

If I replace my custom editor to DropdownCellEditor - it's ok.

```
  editor: new Y.DropDownCellEditor({options: {
        apple: 'Apple',
        banana: 'Banana',
        cherry: 'Cherry',
        kiwi: 'Kiwi'
  }}),
```

Can someone explain what's going wrong ?

Code I'm trying to make workable: http://jsfiddle.net/tu89ap1o/1/

I would be very happy if some shares good documentation for AlloUI framework. 
Or suggest good library for building diagrams. Goals: need to have possibility to build custom nodes with different set of properties and edit them.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of debugging obfuscating code I've found that hide function works by just adding into class: your editor name plus '-hidden', so to make it workable need to add :

`.mycustomcelleditor-hidden {
    display: none;
}`

into css, stupid implementation BTW.